# Dynamically add img alt tags within HTML markup in PHP

Tags: php, html, alt

I have HTML in which I echo onto a page using HTML. The HTML markup contains images, some of which don't have alt tags.  There is no set format for the image markup - as it was exported from WordPress, which has messed around with the formatting.

I need to be able to parse the HTML, find the images without an alt tag, or an empty alt tag and populate that with text.

Comment: Please some code.  and some more info : do you output the content of the HTML file with PHP ? are the "img" tags produced by php or are static html ?

Comment: @Federico as I said in my post, I echo the HTML onto the page, the HTML has 'img' tags in it - none of them are in a specific format.

Comment: We can only help you if you show us the code you have and where it isn't working. If you have trouble with how to approach this problem at all, I would advise an approach similar to **[this](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html)** where you check for the existance of a `alt` property.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

It try to find the **img** without the **alt** property or width empty **alt=""**.

than replace the images with  **alt=" my_text "**

```
$content = '
replace alt <img src="aaaa" alt="" />
replace alt <img src="bbbb" alt=" " />
replace alt <img src="cccc" />
do nothing  <img src="dddd" alt="xxxxxxx" />
do nothing  <img src="eeee" alt="yyyyy" />
error:      <img src="ffff" alt="" alt="  " />
';

function replace_alt($html_content, $alt_text='')
{   $count = preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $html_content, $images);
    if($count>0)
    {   $o = $html_content;
        $t = 'alt="'.$alt_text.'" ';
        foreach($images[0] as $img)
        {   $is_alt = preg_match_all('/ alt="([^"]*)"/i', $img, $alt);
            if($is_alt==0)
            {   $new_img = str_replace('<img ', '<img '.$t , $img);
                $o = str_replace($img, $new_img, $o);
            }
            elseif($is_alt==1)
            {   $text = trim($alt[1][0]);
                if(empty($text))
                {   $new_img = str_replace(trim($alt[0][0]), $t, $img);
                    $o = str_replace($img, $new_img, $o);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $o;
}

echo replace_alt($content, 'TEST');
```

**$content** should be your full HTML page....

Comment: I think this would work - how do I get it to search for: alt="", alt=" " and just no alt at all?

Comment: I have updated it now it also find & replace empty alt